# In wordpress HTML code cannot print in if statement

Tags: php, wordpress

I found a weird thing that the HTML code under if statement is not able to print out, I check the html source code and could not find it.

Here is part of the code:

```
<div id="block-subheaderbar">
    <?php if (count($sub_menu = wp_nav_menu(array('sub_menu' => true))) ) : ?>
    <div class="wrapper max-width80">
        <header id="header" class="clearfix ">
            <?php wp_nav_menu(array('sub_menu' => true)); ?>
        </header>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

The code:

```
<div class="wrapper max-width80">
<header id="header" class="clearfix ">
```

cannot print out in html, could you explain why? and how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem here is your if case wp_nav-menu() function use instead

```
<?php if (count($sub_menu = wp_nav_menu(array('sub_menu' => true,'echo' => 0))) ) : ?>
```

this might do if yor sub_menu argument is working